# counting records per group

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I have 3 group fields in my report, my details section only contains 1 field of data, I tried creating a formula with `count()` to count the number of records in the details section but it counts everything, how do I get my formula to consider the groups?

Answer (score 2):

Place field into details section, insert summary (count) field into correct group header/footer, delete field from details. Done :)

Of course you can use formula too - aggregate formulas (sum etc) can have second parameter to specify grouping level.

Comment: Is it possible to add more than 1 group for the second parameter?

Comment: No, but what should that mean anyway?

Comment: I have 3 groups in my report, I added the parameter to the count function but of course it only considers 1 of the groups and not all 3.